# return back() in Laravel without session params

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have this code in a project with Laravel 5:

```
return back()->with('msg_ok','successfully sent');
```

The `param msg_ok` is pushed in Session, but I´m not want use session params, I want pass the msg_ok parameter as variable.

For example I want print this en my blade file:

```
{{ $msg_ok }}
```

Comment: You could append it to the querystring as a GET parameter. But apart from that and sessions, you're pretty much limited to persisting the variable elsewhere, like in a database or a file, and I'm sure you don't want that.

Comment: So basically you want a query string parameter like: `?msg_ok=the+message!`. If not it's not possible without sessions. (@JoelHinz just beat me to it)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel `back()` function will always return data in a `Session`. Normally you can't return variable with `back()` function. You have to use `view()` function for that.

**Alternate Solution**
You can use `keep()` function for storing data in session like variable. Which will not be flushed after refresh.

**e.g**
$request->session()->keep(['username', 'email']);

and then get data with key.

Answer (score -1):

Laravel **back()** will redirect you back from the form where it is submitted,
and back()->with('msg_ok', 'successfully..');

if you place an item inside back()->with(); it will automatically place the value
inside session.

You can use `return redirect()->to('url/path?msg_ok=successfully')` add the query string parameter to url to pass it as variable.

and then on the controller where you have been redirected inject the Reqest class to your method

e.g

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    $msg_ok = $request->get('msg_ok', '');
    return view('view.blade', compact('msg_ok'));
}
```

Place the variable string inside the compact to make it accessible to your view.

Answer (score -2):

You can just use `Session::get('msg_ok')` in your blade file. Or pass the variable to the view explicitly, in controller, like
`return view()->make('view', ['msg_ok' => session()->get('msg_ok')]);`

Comment: Yes but I don´t want use Session::get, I want use back() + pass a variable $msg_ok

Comment: First of all your statement is not clear about what exacly you want to do. Second thing, since ``back()`` is actually a 301 response, it will cause a redirect, thus the new request will be created(in which you won't have access to $msg_ok unless you pull it from session like I said).